# Polling request sometimes gives 302 found - socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have created a chat application using node.js (version-9.6.1) and socket.io (version-2.1.1). On opening my chat app using url http://localhost:3003/chat everything works fine including polling requests that i can see in my network section of chrome.

**Polling URL**: http://localhost:3003/socket.io/?uid=86e5b2effc551a7629f3a8f9f551092d&source=M&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MWnIf7C&sid=AxnCANFBlBXIiO-VAAAU

**Request Method**: POST
**Status Code**: 200 OK

**Problem** : After 5-10 minutes, a request goes whose response comes with
status Code 302,due to which uid from url http://localhost:3003/chat?uid= gets removed and chat app stop working.

**Solutions tried**:

I have searched for related error like 404 across stack overflow, it might be due to different versions of socket.io on client and server side, but in my case both are same.

I have also tried deleting node_modules folder and reinstalling node packages,but still facing the same issue.